# Creating a stack for use in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, inner-classes

I am trying to implement a binary search tree using iterative methods only. As such, I need to have a stack for things like traversal, etc. I am not allowed to use the predefined stack structure in C++ so I am trying to implement my own using linked lists. I am having troubles doing so partly because of restrictions such as being unable to modify the BST class itself, I am only able to add helper classes. Basically, I am trying to store a BST Node inside of a LL node. Is this possible and/or is there a better way? Here is my current attempt which does not compile but I'm not sure how to fix:

```
class BST {
private:
struct Node {
    string value;
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
};

Node * head;

public:
class LinkedList {
private:
    struct LLNode {
        Node * val;
        LLNode * next;
    };
    LLNode * head;
    LLNode * tail;
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void add(Node * s) {
        LLNode * p = new LLNode;
        p->val = s;
        p->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL && tail == NULL) {
          head = p;
          tail = p;
        }
        else if (head == tail) {
            head->next = p;
            tail = p;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = p;
            tail = p;
        }
    }
};
BST();
~BST();
void test() {
  BST * test = new BST;
  LinkedList * newstack = new LinkedList;
  newstack->add(test);
  return;
};
```

Comment: [Consider using `std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) in place of your linked list. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I can't use predefined data structures in c++ for this task. If I want to use a stack, I have to implement one myself.

Comment: OK. Might I suggest that you use a stack based on a simple resizable array? Much easier to get working than a linked list, and because it maintains a contiguous data store, almost always faster. If a push will over flow the array, allocate a new one twice the size, copy the old array into the new one, delete the old array, and point the stack at the new array.

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't aware that I could create an array for nodes. So it'd be an array of Node pointers correct?

Comment: Yeah, it ventures into two star programming, `Node ** array;`, but if you want a dynamic array of pointers you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Why do you create another struct `LLNode`? Your Tree (or BST) structure should just consist of one root `Node` and methods that perform tree operations.